# What is the official procedure for starting a hand in texas holdem heads up?

Tags: texas-hold-em, dealing, dealer

As a dealer what are the steps I need to perform when dealing a hand during a heads up?
E.g.

1. Move Button to player 1
2. Collect BB from player 2
3. Collect SB from player 1
4. First card goes to...?

A reference is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key is the button represents the dealer,  the dealer doesn't deal himself/herself first.  So, the first card goes to the big blind player in heads-up.

> According to heads up poker rules, the dealer posts the small blind and the other player posts the big blind. The first card is dealt to the player in the Big Blind. The dealer acts first pre-flop and the big blind acts first on the flop, turn, and river. The dealer always goes last on the flop, turn, and river.

from link mentioned below

https://automaticpoker.com/poker-basics/heads-up-game-play-rules-for-texas-holdem/

From Wikipedia:

> When only two players remain, special 'head-to-head' or 'heads up' rules are enforced and the blinds are posted differently. In this case, the person with the dealer button posts the small blind, while his/her opponent places the big blind. The dealer acts first before the flop. After the flop, the dealer acts last and continues to do so for the remainder of the hand.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_hold_%27em

Comment: Also note: when the game (or tournament) goes from more than two players down to head-up, the button is first awarded to the player who most recently posted the big blind, regardless of its previous position.